# storing input from a separate class

Tags: java

I posted a question earlier for a homework assignment but I have a new question. I am new at this so  I appreciate any help I can get and I'm not looking for code but more of an explanation of the steps I need to take to get to my answer.

I'm working on an address book. The user picks a menu 1, 2, or 3. I have a main class, a validation class, a class that declares set and get and a class that handles the IO functions.

I'm just learning classes so please be patient but basically I want to understand how to save the info if the user wants to enter a new person.
I have  a setName and getName and a setPhoneNumber and getPhoneNumber in a class I also have the function to save everything written in the IO class that was provided. I don't understand what saves the information I guess is what I'm saying. Do I need to create a scanner for each line? or How do I send it to the right place? 
Do I need to call the whole function that is in the IO class that handles the name and phone number?

```
   if(menuNumber == 2)
{
   System.out.println("Enter name: ")

   System.out.println("enter phone number: ")
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm taking classes online and so far java hasn't been an easy one. I want to understand it but I'm struggling through this book and my projects have a pretty quick turnaround so I want to learn it but I almost need to stop and ask for someone to break it down for me in english instead of staring at a diagram in a book.

Comment: If you keep your cursor on the java tag above you'll see a link called "info".. on that page you'll see a link "The Java Tutorials ".. then Essential Java Classes and finally you'll come to Basic I/O.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html.. read up..

Comment: @thekashyap Thanks! I'm new to this site and did not know that was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of steps:
1) prompt user for value
2) get value, store in local variable
3) create new instance of class that holds data
4) pass locals to setters

If you read this from a file put these steps in a loop. Keep reusing the local variables. If one of your constructors takes a variable you can call that as soon as you get the first piece of data. For example (pseudo code);

```
out- enter name
in- name
localString name_ = name
MyClass newPerson = newPerson(name_)
out- enter phone number
in- 503-495-4950
localPhoneNumber phoneNum = 503-495-4950
newPerson.setPhoneNumber(phoneNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you have written your IO functions.

Write your IO function such that it takes Person object as argument. Then you could open a file and write the attributes of Person as string.

You could go for [Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/). It much neater and helpful if you want to recreate objects from file.